# Extract the maximum and minimum number of strings in a column - Using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID            Name
LM10          Messi
CR7           Ronaldo
NR10JR        Neymar
```

from the above df, I would like to know the maximum and minimum number of strings in a column `ID`

For Example:

`LM10` has 4 strings (4 letters or characters)

`CR7` has 3 strings  - So the minimum is 3

`NR10JR` has 6 strings - so the maximum is 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with `min` and `max`:

```
lens = df['ID'].str.len()
print (lens)
0    4
1    3
2    6
Name: ID, dtype: int64

min1, max1 = lens.min(), lens.max()
print (min1, max1)
3 6
```

Or for output to `Series` add [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html):

```
out = df['ID'].str.len().agg(['min','max'])
print (out)
min    3
max    6
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Kindly check this in your free time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67701249/calculate-age-in-days-from-date-column-based-availability-actual-date-birth-el/67701598#67701598